# "Error: \"throw $continue\" is deprecated, use \"return\" instead"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, prototype, railscasts

I am following [railscast to generate complex form](http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2)

I am receiving this error:-

```
 "Error: \"throw $continue\" is deprecated, use \"return\" instead"
```

Any idea?

I am receiving this error when I am trying to add a new question.

Comment: @mu is too short  http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2 includes all the code.. check it.. let me know if its not fine.. I will paste the same code here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From railscast:--

```
def link_to_add_fields(name, f, association)
  new_object = f.object.class.reflect_on_association(association).klass.new
  fields = f.fields_for(association, new_object, :child_index => "new_#{association}") do |builder|
  render(association.to_s.singularize + "_fields", :f => builder)
  end
 link_to_function(name, h("add_fields(this, \"#{association}\", \"#{escape_javascript(fields)}\")"))
end
```

Remove h in link_to_function ie

```
def link_to_add_fields(name, f, association)
  new_object = f.object.class.reflect_on_association(association).klass.new
  fields = f.fields_for(association, new_object, :child_index => "new_#{association}") do |builder|
  render(association.to_s.singularize + "_fields", :f => builder)
  end
 link_to_function(name, ("add_fields(this, \"#{association}\", \"#{escape_javascript(fields)}\")"))
end
```